# preg_replace how to replace only matching xxx($1)yyy pattern inside the selector

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-match, regex-group

I'm trying to use a regular expression to erase only the matching part of an string.  I'm using the `preg_replace` function and have tried to delete the matching text by putting parentheses around the matching portion. Example:

```
preg_replace('/text1(text2)text3/is','',$html);
```

This replaces the entire string with '' though.  I only want to erase text2, but leave text1 and text3 intact.  How can I match and replace just the part of the string that matches?

Answer (score 58):

Use [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (i.e. brackets) to keep only the parts of the expression that you want to remember. You can recall the contents in the replacement string by using `$1`, `$2`, etc.:

```
preg_replace('/(text1)text2(text3)/is','$1$2',$html);
```

Answer (score 49):

There is an alternative to using `text1` and `text3` in the match pattern and then putting them back in via the replacement string. You can use **assertions** like this:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=text1)(text2)(?=text3)/', "", $txt);
```

This way the regular expression looks just for the *presence*, but does not take the two strings into account when applying the replacement.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for more information.

Comment: Backreferences may be preferable if your lookbehind pattern does not produce a fixed length match

Comment: There're no needs to capture `text2`

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
$text = preg_replace("'(text1)text2(text3)'is", "$1$2", $text);
```

Hope it works!

**Edit:** changed `\\1\\2` to `$1$2` which is the recommended way.

Comment: Please use $n instead of \\n.

Comment: @NikiC is it only style or you have some reason behind it?

Comment: Use of $n over \\n is the official recommendation, quoting the manual: "[...] may contain references of the form \\n or (since PHP 4.0.4) $n, with the latter form being the preferred one". I don't know the exact reasoning behind this, but the $ syntax is at least a) more readable and b) has support for ${n} as well. Maybe there are additional reasons.

Comment: @NikiC so it is indeed a recommendation, I'll keep it in mind, thanks! It's hard to leave behind old habits.

Comment: Better use this in 2018: http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score -5):

The simplest way has been mentioned several types. Another idea is lookahead/lookback, they're overkill this time but often quite useful.