# Only replace matching group with preg_replace()?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

When using `preg_replace()`, is it possible to only replace a matching group in "()" instead of replacing everything in the pattern parameter?

For example, consider this URL:

```
$url = 'http://images.example.com/foo/1234/bar/foobar';
```

To replace the number with another one, I tried doing this:

```
$newUrl = preg_replace('#\/foo\/([0-9]+)\/#', 4321, $url);
```

But the result is this:

```
http://images.example.com4321bar/foobar
```

So it appears that `preg_replace()` replaces everything in the pattern parameter instead of just the matching group.

Is there any way to only replace the matching group instead of replacing everything in the pattern parameter?

Comment: Why don't you try `\K`? `$newUrl = preg_replace('#\/foo\/\K([0-9]+)\/#', 4321, $url);` http://regex101.com/r/eF8fY4/2

Comment: Whats your expected output

Comment: @hwnd I'm just wanting to replace the number in the URL, so in this case the expected output would be `http://images.example.com/foo/4321/bar/foobar`

Comment: Or just with lookarounds, [preg\_replace how to replace only matching xxx($1)yyy pattern inside the selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4898192)